# Prove or disprove this inequality for $x<y$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove or disprove this inequality for $x<y$:

$$(2^{x}-1)^{y}<(2^{y}-1)^{x}$$

I assume that $y=x+r$ for $r>0$ and I consider the function $$f(x)=(2^{x}-1)^{x+r}-(2^{x+r}-1)^{x}$$
 I wante to see the behavior of $f$ with respect to $x$. I've calculated the derivative but it is very complicated to determine its sign. The derivative is: $$ln((((2^{x}-1)^{(2^{x}-1)^{r+x}})/((2^{r+x}-1)^{(2^{r+x}-1)^{x}}))(((2^{2^{x}r(2^{x}-1)^{r+x-1}})(2^{ 2^{x}x(2^{x}-1)^{r+x-1}}))/(2^{2^{r+x}x(2^{r+x}-1)^{x-1}})))$$

Comment: I did. Now what?

Comment: @DER, I think you're being hinted to show some self work, some self effort you've done to solve this.

Comment: @DER As a user with 933 reputation, I expect you already know that the process on this site is you 1) try to solve the problem on your own, 2) include your attempts and thoughts in your question and 3) when posting the question, **ASK** not **DEMAND** it.

Comment: @5xum: I wante to see a proof or a special case that does not verifying this.

Comment: @DER And we want to see a proof that you already did some work and have some ideas in how to proceed before we help you.

Comment: @5xum: I've add some of my efforts to solve this problem.

Comment: what kind of numbers are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Real numbers. But one can consider some integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality doesn't make sense for negative values of the variables, so we can assume that $0\lt x\lt y$ is intended, in which case the inequality amounts to saying that the function

$$f(x)={1\over x}\ln(2^x-1)$$

is increasing for $x\gt0$.  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume both $x$ and $y$ are positive, to avoid nonreal values.

**Analysis.** Letting $p=\frac yx>1$, the desired inequality would follow from
$$ (2^x-1)^p \le 2^{px}-1 $$
Equivalently,
$$ p\ln(2^x-1) \le \ln(2^{px}-1) $$
This suggests considering the function $f(x)=\ln(2^x-1)$.  Here is a (qualitatively roughly correct, but quantitatively quite inaccurate) sketch:

[image: sketch]

Based on this sketch we certainly expect that $pf(x)\le f(px)$.  One way to formulate the relevant properties of the sketch rigorously is to say that $(px,f(px))$ is closer to the asymptote $y=x\ln 2$ than $(x,f(x))$ is, while $(px,pf(x))$ is further away.  This approach yields the following argument.

**Proof.** Check that
$$ t\ln 2 - \ln(2^t-1) = \ln\left(\frac{2^t}{2^t-1}\right) $$
is a strictly decreasing and positive for $t>0$.  Thus $x<y$ implies
\begin{align*}
y\ln 2 - \ln(2^y-1)
&< x\ln 2 - \ln(2^x-1) \\
&< \frac yx (x\ln 2 - \ln(2^x-1)) \\
&= y\ln 2 - \frac yx \ln(2^x-1)
\end{align*}
Now simplify.